# Android parcelable for android objects like mediaplayer

Tags: android

I have searched today how to make `Parcelable` to share some objects between activities through `intent`. The all examples I found are with custom objects with basic data like `int`/`string`/`arraylists` etc. Is there a way to make a parcelable of a `MediaPlayer` object ? So far I have this:

```
public class mpParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeValue(mp);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<mpParcelable> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<mpParcelable>() {
        public mpParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new mpParcelable(in);
        }

        public mpParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new mpParcelable[size];
        }
    };

    private mpParcelable(Parcel in) {
        mp = in.readValue();
    }
}
```

The part where I don't know what todo is on `setter` if I can say like that: where `mp = in.readValue();` I don't know how to read the `MediaPlayer` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make a parcelable of a MediaPlayer object ?

No, because that is not your class. Occasionally, you can create a wrapper around some other class and the wrapper can be `Parcelable`, but I do not see how this would work with a `MediaPlayer`.

IMHO, what you want (sharing a `MediaPlayer` between components) is a code smell. Either each component should have its own `MediaPlayer`, or the `MediaPlayer` should be centrally managed (e.g., via a service).

Comment: Understand, so I need a service to work with MediaPlayer, thanks.